# AttributeError: 'IsInvited' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have a modelviewset like this:

```
class MeetingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Meeting.objects.all()

serializer_class = MeetingSerializer
permission_classes =[IsAuthenticated & IsInvited | IsOwner]
```

and permissions:

```
class IsInvited(BasePermission):
message = 'you must have been invited to see this meeting'

def has_object_permission(self, object, request, view):
  
    if self.request.method == 'GET' and object.is_invited(self.request.user):
        return True
        
    return False

class IsOwner(BasePermission):


def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

def has_object_permission(self, object, request, view):
    
    if self.request.user == object.host:
        return True
    
    return False
```

but i got this error :

```
    Internal Server Error: /api/meetings/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 54, in retrieve
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 99, in get_object
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 345, in check_object_permissions
    if not permission.has_object_permission(request, self, obj):
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 81, in has_object_permission
    self.op1.has_object_permission(request, view, obj) or
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 64, in has_object_permission
    self.op2.has_object_permission(request, view, obj)
  File "/home/admin1/mizbanproject/mizban_events/meeting/api/permissions.py", line 14, in has_object_permission
    return request.method == 'GET' and object.is_invited(request.user)
AttributeError: 'MeetingViewSet' object has no attribute 'method'
```

IsOwner works perfectly and i only got this error in IsInvited,  i am confused and don't know how to solve this bug .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has_object_permission` method can not use `self.request` to obtain the request, since a `BasePermission` does not contain the `request`: the request is passed as a parameter, so you can implement this wsith:

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, object):
    return request.method == 'GET' and object.is_invited(request.user)
    #         ↑             no self.request                 ↑
```

The order of the parameters is also different: it is `self`, `object`, `view` and `rquest`.

Your permissions thus can look like:

```
class IsInvited(BasePermission):
    message = 'you must have been invited to see this meeting'
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, object):
        if return request.method == 'GET' and object.is_invited(request.user)


class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, object):
        return request.user == object.host
```

Comment: now i get this error : AttributeError: 'MeetingViewSet' object has no attribute 'method'

Comment: Please share the full traceback, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68627573/edit) your question.

Comment: Your `IsOwner` has by the way the same problem, you should rewrite `self.request` to `request`.

Comment: but i did not get the error using self in IsOwner and it works!that is why i am confused

Comment: @niloofar: likely because the `has_permission` alwyas rejected that.

Comment: now i get this error : AttributeError: 'MeetingViewSet' object has no attribute 'method' . any suggestion?

Comment: @niloofar: you swapped the parameter order for `view` and `request`: it should be first `view` and *then* `request`.

Comment: @niloofar: this is for *both* `IsInvited` and `IsOwner`.

Comment: still the same error in this line : return request.method == 'GET' and object.is_invited(request.user), i swapped view and request in both

Comment: @niloofar: ok, updated the *answer* with the correct parameter order: first `request`, then `view`, and *then* `object`.